# How can I zoom into an object and follow that object in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this bullet which is shot by a tank. The cam should follow this shot and like zoom into it. How can I do this?

https://youtu.be/NLUqaVCyCk4 this is what I have so far

Comment: "The cam should follow this shot and like zoom into it." Well, is there an actual camera? Do you know how to set its position? Do you know how to figure out where the bullet is? Do you know how to change the zoom of the camera? *What actually is the difficulty?*

Comment: Is there a cam? no
Do you know how to set its position? no
Do you know how to figure out where the bullet is? yes
Do you know how to change the zoom of the camera? no

Comment: Okay, so the next step is to do some [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For example, did you try putting `pygame camera` into a search engine?

Comment: Well yes, but when I go on there website, something weird appears http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html

Comment: this is link to functions which give access to hardware `camera` but you don't need hardware `camera` but something what usually is called `"camera"` or `"viewport"` and it let scroll bigger area and display in window only small part.

Comment: to follow object you would have to get distance (x,y) between this object and center of window and later substract (x,y) from all objects before displaying - but don't save new value but keep original value (to use it in next frame).

Comment: as for zooming: you can create new `Surface()`, draw all on this surface (instead of drawing in window), rescale this surface and finally display rescaled surface in window - this way you will zoom all elements at once.

Comment: frankly, with viewport you could also use new Surface, draw all items, and finally display it in window but moved - using distance between shot at center of screen.

Answer (score 0):

First you could create new `surface` and draw all objects on this `surface`, later you can make some modification (like scale for zooming), and finally you can blit it in window. This way you can modify (zoom, move) all objects at once.

---

To follow player (and keep it in center) you can calculate distance (x,y) between player and center of window. And later you can use it to blit `surface` in window.

```
    if follow_player:
        surface_rect.x = (screen_rect.centerx - player_rect.centerx)
        surface_rect.y = (screen_rect.centery - player_rect.centery)
    else:
        surfac_rect.center = screen_rect.center
```

---

To zoom you can use scale surface and later blit it.

```
    if zoom:
        scale = 2
        surface = pygame.transform.rotozoom(surface, 0, scale)
        surface_rect = surface.get_rect()
    else:
        scale = 1
```

If you want to use both then you may need to use `scale` when you calculate distance

```
        surface_rect.x = (screen_rect.centerx - player_rect.centerx * scale)
        surface_rect.y = (screen_rect.centery - player_rect.centery * scale)
```

---

Minimal working code.

Face is moving randomly all time.

Use `SPACE` to switch `follow_player`, and `ENTER` to switch `zoom`

[image]

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

surface = pygame.surface.Surface( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

# --- objects ---

bg_image = pygame.image.load('lenna.png').convert()
bg_rect  = bg_image.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

player_image = pygame.image.load("face.png").convert()
player_rect  = player_image.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

follow_player = False
zoom = False

#number = 0  # to generate images for animated `gif` 
             # `ffmpeg -i image-%03d.jpg -vf scale=250:200 video.gif`

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                follow_player = not follow_player

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                zoom = not zoom

    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    move_x = random.randint(-5, 5)
    move_y = random.randint(-5, 5)
    player_rect.move_ip(move_x, move_y)

    # --- draw on surface ---

    surface.fill(BLACK)
    surface.blit(bg_image, bg_rect)
    surface.blit(player_image, player_rect)

    # --- modify surface ---
    
    surface_mod = surface.copy()
    surface_mod_rect = surface_mod.get_rect()

    if zoom:
        scale = 2
        surface_mod = pygame.transform.rotozoom(surface_mod, 0, scale)
        surface_mod_rect = surface_mod.get_rect()
    else:
        scale = 1
        
    if follow_player:
        surface_mod_rect.x = (screen_rect.centerx - player_rect.centerx*scale)
        surface_mod_rect.y = (screen_rect.centery - player_rect.centery*scale)
    else:
        surface_mod_rect.center = screen_rect.center

    # --- draw surface on screen ---
    
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    screen.blit(surface_mod, surface_mod_rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    
    #pygame.image.save(screen, f"image-{number:03}.jpg")   
    #number += 1

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

**lenna.png** (from Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna))

[image]

**face.png**

[image]